# Agrupar hijos respecto al Padre en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo una app con React que tiene un Menú y un submenú dinámicos que se crean a través de un json. En base a ese json el menú sería "Padre" y los hijos serían "Hijo".Con el código que tengo ahora mismo en console.log veo todos los padres por un lado y los hijos por otro y necesito que cada padre se vea por separado pero cada hijo se agrupe en un submenú respecto al padre. Me explico:

CRM debe mostrar:

- Argumentarios

Permisos debe mostrar:

- Root (solo una vez)

Telefonía debe mostrar:

- Configuración
- Rutas

Este es un ejemplo de mi json:

```
[
   {
      "Id":"114",
      "Padre":"CRM",
      "Hijo":"Argumentarios"
   },
   {
      "Id":"115",
      "Padre":"CRM",
      "Hijo":"Argumentarios"
   },
      "Id":"44",
      "Padre":"Permisos",
      "Hijo":"root"
   },
   {
      "Id":"45",
      "Padre":"Permisos",
      "Hijo":"root"
   },
   {
      "Id":"50",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Audio"
   },
   {
      "Id":"52",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Configuracion"
   },
   {
      "Id":"70",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Rutas"
   }
]
```

Todo esto se muestra en el console.log por lo que ocurre en componentWillMount

Una vez se muestre todo correctamente en el console.log me gustaría saber cómo puedo pintar los resultados en mi html. Hasta ahora estoy utilizando {this.props.submenu} para mostrar los elementos del submenú y {this.props.menu} para mostrar los del menú, aunque con esta configuración no me funcionan.
Este es mi código.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Icon from './Icon';

class Nav extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            menuSubmenu:[],
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('fakejson_menu.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(menuSubmenu =>{

            const padres = new Set();
            const hijos = new Set();

            menuSubmenu.forEach(dato => {
            padres.add(dato.Padre);
            hijos.add(dato.Hijo);

            });


            console.log('Padres');
            for (let item of padres) menuSubmenu.push(item);
            console.log('Hijos');
            for (let item of hijos) console.log(item);

        })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.menuSubmenu.length > 0) {
          return(
            <nav className="nav">
                <div className="menu">
                    <ul className="list">
                            {this.state.menuSubmenu.map(datos => <Menu key={datos.Id} menu={datos.Padre} submenu={datos.Hijo} descripcion={datos.Description} url={datos.Url} submenuClick={this.submenuClick}/>)}
                    </ul>

                    <div className="content-bnt">
                        <button id="desplegar" className='btn btn--rounded'>
                            <Icon icon="flecha" className='ico-flecha'/>
                        </button>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </nav>
          );
        }
        return (<p>Cargando usuarios...</p>);
    }
}

class Menu extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            abrirSubmenu: false,
        }
        this.submenuClick = this.submenuClick.bind(this);
    }

    submenuClick() {
        this.setState(state => ({
            abrirSubmenu: !state.abrirSubmenu
          }));
        //alert('Click!')
    }
    render(){
        return (
                <li key={this.props.id} className="list__item">
                    <button title={this.props.menu} id={"mn-" + this.props.menu} className="desplegable" onClick={this.submenuClick.bind(this)}><Icon icon="auriculares" className='ico-auriculares'/>{this.props.menu}</button>
                {
                this.state.abrirSubmenu
                    ? (
                    <div id="sb-crm" className="submenu">
                        <h3 className="nav--title"><Icon icon="descargar" className='ico-descargar'/>{this.props.submenu}</h3>
                        <ul className="list">
                            <li className="list__item">
                                <a href={this.props.url} title={this.props.descripcion}>{this.props.descripcion}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    )
                    : (
                    null
                    )
                }
                </li>
        )
    }
}

export default Nav;
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un método de la clase `Array` llamado [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce), que lo que hace es *reducir* un array a un único elemento mientras se recorre todo el array. Funciona así:

```
array.reduce(function (acumulado, elemento, indice) {
  ...
  return acumulado;
}, valorInicial);
```

Partiendo de un objeto vacío, podrías ir creando la jerarquía que necesitas (asumo que tu menú sólo tendrá dos niveles):

```js
const datosJson= [
  { "Id": "114", "Padre": "CRM", "Hijo": "Argumentarios" },
  { "Id": "115", "Padre": "CRM", "Hijo": "Argumentarios" },
  { "Id": "44", "Padre": "Permisos", "Hijo": "root" },
  { "Id": "45", "Padre": "Permisos", "Hijo": "root" },
  { "Id": "50", "Padre": "Telefonia", "Hijo": "Audio" },
  { "Id": "52", "Padre": "Telefonia", "Hijo": "Configuracion" },
  { "Id": "70", "Padre": "Telefonia", "Hijo": "Rutas" }
]

let jerarquia= datosJson.reduce((acc,elem) => {
  acc[elem.Padre] = acc[elem.Padre] || [];
  if (!acc[elem.Padre].includes(elem.Hijo)) {
    acc[elem.Padre].push((elem.Hijo));
  }
  return acc;
},{});

console.log(jerarquia)
```